# How can I block the user input entering commas in case of negative decimals with regex in typescript angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, form-control

I have a component directive shared for all fields, but I want to add a rule for a field specific, this field block user input commas, I have the following code in file ts but it only satisfies the condition for positive decimals (ex: 2323.34343) else case negative decimals (ex: -3232.323) I can't enter a minus sign because of the regex check function not match with the first character being the minus sign.
How can I fix it? pls help me, thanks a lot!!!!

```
  private el: HTMLInputElement;

  private check(value: string) {
            const regExpString = "^-?\\s*((\\d+(\\.\\d{0,5})?)|((\\d*(\\.\\d{1,5}))))\\s*$";
            return String(value).match(new RegExp(regExpString));
    }
```

````
    @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
    onKeyDown(v) {
            const value: string = this.el.value;
            const next: string = value.concat(v.key); 
            console.log(this.check(next))
            if (next && !this.check(next)) { 
                v.preventDefault();
            }
    }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Through HTML file - Apply validations for numbers or alphabets in html file using "pattern".

Through TS file - Use ASCII values for comma validations. If user enters a comma, ASCII code for comma will be matched. Use if else .